# Placement of svg objects in a webview

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, webview, ionic-framework

I am currently trying to centrally(vertically & horizontally) align a multiple tspan's inside a text object in a (Android and iOS) webview.

As of now, I have an array of json objects, the key-value pair corresponds to attribute & their values. I use d3 to render this into an svg, this process occurs inside an ionic app.

On the browser side, all is well, moving to the mobile client however, groups refuse to pass down their attributes to their children. A problem in itself, but on hat has been worked around.

The real issue is now, aligning the wrapped text inside an svg text object, which are in tspans. I could code a solution to get the BBox or something along those lines, calculate that, then take the x coordinate & the width/2 calculate the offset, also using a similiar process for the y coordinate.

TLDR:
Is there a way in which to either make a webview act more to the specifications? Or how would one go about centering the tspans inside it's parent container, without coding the mechanic?

Comment: did u add text-anchor="middle" to your tspan

Comment: I hadn't but I have now, still no luck. The problem is no properties are being inherited from it's parents. I've managed to work around most of them, but this one appears to be the clincher.

Comment: can you put up a fiddle else it will be like shooting arrows in the dark..

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using transforms instead of attributes. I didn't realise attributes to not affect there children. I might be wrong with that, but I can tell you a translate transform as solved the issue.